# How can I unit test a method that depends on a volatile variable in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, unit-testing

Here's a simplified version of my class:

```
@interface RTMovieBuilder : NSObject
@property (atomic, getter = isCancelled) volatile BOOL cancelled;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<BuilderDelegate>delegate;
- (void)moviesFromJSON:(id)JSON;
- (Movie *)movieFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (void)cancel;
@end

@implementation RTMovieBuilder

- (void)moviesFromJSON:(id)JSON
{
    // Check for errors -> If good, then do...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        [self syncrouslyCreateMoviesFromJSON:JSON];
        });
}

- (void)syncrouslyCreateMoviesFromJSON:(id)JSON
{        
    NSMutableArray *movies = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in JSON)
    {
        if ([self isCancelled])
            return;
        else
            [movies addObject:[self movieFromDictionary:dict]];
    }

    [self notifyDelegateCreatedObjects:movies];
}

- (Movie *)movieFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    Movie *movie = [[Movie alloc] init];
    // Set movie properties based on dictionary...
    return movie;
}

- (void)cancel
{
    [self setCancelled:YES];
}

// ... Other methods omitted for brevity's sake

@end
```

The property `cancelled` is `atomic` and `volatile` because it may be accessed by other threads (i.e. the main thread may call `cancel` method to stop the operation). (I believe these are needed, if not, please note why it's not in your answer.)

I am trying to write unit tests to make sure this will work before writing the view controller class.

How can I write a unit test that will simulate a call to `cancel` while `RTMovieBuilder` is in the middle of creating `movies`?

**Edit**

Here's a unit test I have already written which tests to make sure that `notifyDelegateCreatedObjects:` isn't called if `cancel` is called first.

```
- (void)testIfCancelledDoesntNotifyDelegateOfSuccess
{
    // given
    RTMovieBuilder *builder = [[RTMovieBuilder alloc] init];
    builder.delegate = mockProtocol(@protocol(BuilderDelegate));

    // when
    [builder cancel];
    [builder notifyDelegateCreatedObjects:@[]];

    // then
    [verifyCount(builder.delegate, never()) builder:builder createdObjects:anything()];
}
```

I'm using `OCHamcrest` and `OCMockito`. This test passes.

Comment: Seems to me like you're recreating some sort of `NSOperation` object. You might have an easier time using that instead :)

Comment: Sort of... my understanding is that `NSOperation` doesn't actually support canceling an operation's tasks once said tasks have started? I.e., you have to write checks to see `if (cancelled)` and abort, right?

Comment: You're right, though, maybe I should be subclassing `NSOperation` here

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct, but isn't that what you're trying to do here in `syncrouslyCreateMoviesFromJSON` ?

Comment: Yes, that is what the check `if ([self isCancelled])` is for - to abort. I'll rewrite this code to subclass (possibly create?) `NSOperation`s instead. However, wouldn't I still have the same issue of trying to a unit test that simulates canceling an operation that's already started?

Comment: I wonder if you really need to be recreating that threading scenario. It seems the case you need to be testing for is if the call to `notifyDelegateCreatedObjects` happens after the action is canceled, because the cancel came too late. So maybe just unit test the handling of that scenario downstream in your `notifyDelegateCreatedObjects` method, or whatever class is being notified of that aborted event because of the thread timing.

Comment: @foggzilla, I thought of this too and actually wrote the tests (I'll add to the question prompt). Is this good enough? I worry that issues can arise due to threading interactions?

Comment: @JRG-Developer If you are testing for all possible downstream conditions regardless of how the timing falls, then that is enough, imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid trying to simulate thread timing in unit tests and focus more on figuring out what all the possible end states could be regardless of where the timing falls, and write tests for code under those conditions. This avoids endless complexity in your tests, as bbum points out as well.

In your case it seems the condition you need to be testing for is if the call to `notifyDelegateCreatedObjects` happens after the action is canceled, because the cancel came too late. So instead just unit test the handling of that scenario downstream in your `notifyDelegateCreatedObjects` method, or whatever class is being notified of that aborted event because of the thread timing.

I know this is not a specific answer to your question but I think its a better approach to achieve the same unit testing goal.

Comment: I can see how this could lead to endlessly complex unit tests... sounds like this is the (only?) way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `volatile` if your property is `atomic` and you always go through the setter/getter.

As well, this is a bit of re-inventing the wheel, as noted in the comments.

In general trying to unit test cancellation with any hope of full coverage is very hard because you can't really effectively test all possible timing interactions.

Comment: Yes, I will rewrite to use `NSOperation` instead. So basically, unit testing doesn't work well here, then? What would you do to test this interaction, then? (In addition to manual, user testing of course)